# reset Formula for each group (crystal reports)

Tags: crystal-reports

I am adding A formula field in crystal report to calc cumulative balanc and I am using this formula

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared CurrencyVar Amt;

IF {Command.CURRANCY} = '$' 
THEN 
    Amt := Amt + {Command.CREDIT} + {Command.DEBIT} * -1
ELSE
    Amt := Amt + {Command.IQDVALCR} +
{Command.IQDVALDB} * -1
```

But I have a grouping on account and currency, also I want it To be reset At The Group Level What Should I do to fix it?